# Array de arrays regresa nil:NilClass Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una duda de programación en rails, tengo:

```
perimeter_status = [nil, [3,4], [5,6]]
```

Si quiero obtener el valor `perimeter_status[0][1]` este me regresa un error
nil:NilClass por obvias razones. ¿Como pondrían una validación para evitar este
error?

A mi se me ocurría así ,pero siento que esta súper mal hecho.

```
((perimeter_status || [])[location] || [])[perimeter]
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma es que uses el operador [`&` de safe navigation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator), que es más de uso general, o sea no sirve solo para arrays, sino para cualquier objeto ruby:

```
perimeter_status = [nil, [3,4], [5,6]] # => [nil, [3, 4], [5, 6]]
perimeter_status&.[](0)&.[](0) # => nil
perimeter_status&.[](1)&.[](0) # => 3
```

sin embargo, para arrays y hashes tienes el comando [`.dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Array.html#method-i-dig), que te simplifica bastante la tarea y no se ve tan forzado dentro del código:

```
perimeter_status.dig(0, 0) # => nil
perimeter_status.dig(1, 0) # => 3
```